# PowerBi calculate average based on two feilds

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a dataset of Students with grade for each class by semester. I want to calculate their average for each semester in PowerBi

To keep it simple I will show the dataset for one student

| studentId | grade | semester |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 92 | 65 | 568 |
| 92 | 75 | 568 |
| 92 | 80 | 568 |
| 92 | 85 | 568 |
| 92 | 86 | 568 |
| 92 | 88 | 568 |
| 92 | 90 | 568 |
| 92 | 74 | 578 |
| 92 | 86 | 578 |
| 92 | 87 | 578 |
| 92 | 90 | 578 |
| 92 | 92 | 578 |
| 92 | 75 | 582 |
| 92 | 80 | 582 |
| 92 | 85 | 582 |
| 92 | 86 | 582 |
| 92 | 90 | 582 |
| 92 | 100 | 582 |
| 92 | 50 | 586 |
| 92 | 100 | 586 |

In Power Bi I created a table and with studentId, semester, and average of grade. This produced an average that was wrong, Power Bi said the average for period 582 is 88 but if you do the math it is 86. When I add sum(grade) to my table it shows the wrong value for the sum as well (see below)

I think this has to do with 'non-additive' values. So I created DAX calculations:

StudentAvg = AVERAGEX(VALUES(ProgressP[Column1.studentId]),CALCULATE(AVERAGE(ProgressP[grade])))

and

StudentCacAvg =
sum(ProgressP[grade]) / count(ProgressP[grade])

both returned the same result, 88
[image]

I think I am close with the DAX functions but I am missing or not understanding something.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your pasted data is the same as what is in Power BI? You say a simple sum is showing the wrong value for this student for period 582, which is quite baffling.

Comment: I double checked in the backend database and had someone else check as well.

Comment: I am also curious about this. There are some deviations when dividing currency vs real number types. But I don’t think this the case here.

Comment: What do you get when you use Python, Excel or SQL to do the calculation with the data from your source?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the `SUMMARIZE` function.

Given your posted data, in `Table`,

```
Table 2 = SUMMARIZE(
            'Table',
            'Table'[studentId],'Table'[semester],
            "Average", AVERAGE('Table'[grade]))
```

[image]

*You could also generate this table in Power Query, using GroupBy and Average for the Aggregation operation, but you seem to be wanting a DAX solution.*

Comment: No luck, it has to be something with my data set because I have tried 4 different ways and it does not work.

Comment: @PhilipNoah I just copy/pasted the data you posted in your question. If you edit your question to include a copy/paste of the code in the Advanced Editor of Power Query (Transform Data => Advanced Editor), or upload the pbi file to some sharing site, I might be able to help further.